# Moving to other pages in my site using javascript not regular anchors

Tags: jquery, html, performance, seo

I disabled the 'a' anchors at my site, and instead, I created js function that moves the visitor by the `window.location.href` function, for a purpose of-course.
Does this way harm my SEO ranking, or lets say:

- Does this prevent google from crawling my site currectly?
- Does google know that a js is controlling the link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google bot is able to render your javascript if you don't block the resource. Searchengineland made a test, if the google bot can crawl different type of links.

[Google Bot Link Crawling Test](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)